# How to implement adaptive step size Runge-Kutta Cash-Karp?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling, runge-kutta-methods

Trying to implement an adaptive step size Runge-Kutta Cash-Karp but failing with this error:

```
home/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:15: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
```

The ODE i am trying to solve (and using in the example below, transformed from higher order to system of 1st order ODEs) is the following: 
$$u''(x)+u(x)+u(x)^3 =0 ~~{\rm with}~~ u(0)=u'(0)=1 $$

Here is the implementation I am using:

```
def rkck(f, x, y, h, tol):
    #xn = x + h
    err = 2 * tol
    while (err > tol):
        xn = x + h
        k1 = h*f(x,y)
        k2 = h*f(x+(1/5)*h,y+((1/5)*k1)) 
        k3 = h*f(x+(3/10)*h,y+((3/40)*k1)+((9/40)*k2))
        k4 = h*f(x+(3/5)*h,y+((3/10)*k1)-((9/10)*k2)+((6/5)*k3))
        k5 = h*f(x+(1/1)*h,y-((11/54)*k1)+((5/2)*k2)-((70/27)*k3)+((35/27)*k4))
        k6 = h*f(x+(7/8)*h,y+((1631/55296)*k1)+((175/512)*k2)+((575/13824)*k3)+((44275/110592)*k4)+((253/4096)*k5))
        yn4 = y + ((37/378)*k1)+((250/621)*k3)+((125/594)*k4)+((512/1771)*k6)
        yn5 = y + ((2825/27648)*k1)+((18575/48384)*k3)+((13525/55296)*k4)+((277/14336)*k5)+((1/4)*k6)
        err = yn4[-1]-yn5[-1]
        h = 0.8 * h * (tol/err)**(1/float(5))
        yn = yn4
    return xn, yn

def integrate_sStepControl(f, t0, y0, tend, h, tol):
    T = [t0]
    Y = [y0]
    t = t0
    y = y0 
    while (t < tend):
        h = min(h, tend-t)
        t, y = rkck(f, t, y, h, tol)
        T.append(t)
        Y.append(y)
    return np.array(T), np.array(Y)

def f_1(t,y): 
    return np.array([ y[1], -y[0]-(y[0])**3 ])

Y0_f1 = np.array([1.0,1.0])


# Execution
h = 0.05
tv, yv = integrate_sStepControl(f=f_1, t0=0.0, y0=Y0_f1, tend=100.0, h=h, tol=1.0E-05)
print("[ %20.15f, %20.15f]"%(yv[-1,0], yv[-1,1]) )
plt.plot(tv, yv)
```

Getting the error above, but it gets plotted. Don't know what I am doing wrong here :-/ 
[image: plot]

Comment: There is only one place where you divide by a non-constant, in `tol/err`. As the computed value of `h` is not used further, this error does not influence the further computation.

Comment: But is my implementation of the adaptive size control (rkck) method right?

Comment: Why do you think the last component is always dominant for the error? You need to use some norm of the error, else you could get a sign change in the step size. Correcting that should give step sizes oscillating in the range 0.17..0.27

Comment: You're right! But dont know how to do that

Comment: Answered at the cross-post https://stackoverflow.com/a/55863292/3088138